# How to display categories seperated from subcategories Django

Tags: python, django

I've create a **model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Kategoria(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Kategoria')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,verbose_name='Adres SEO')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'parent',)
        verbose_name = 'Kategoria'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Kategorie'

    def __str__(self):
        full_path = [self.name]
        k = self.parent

        while k is not None:
            full_path.append(k.name)
            k = k.parent

        return ' / '.join(full_path[::-1])

class Firma(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, verbose_name='Użytkownik', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Nazwa firmy')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, verbose_name='Adres SEO')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Kategoria', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Kategoria', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='Opis')
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Szablon')
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Firma'
        verbose_name_plural='Firmy'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This model create a categories as parent and subcategories as children. After that I can create a post in Firma class and connect with subcategory or category. In my **view.py** I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Kategoria, Firma



def widok_kategorii(request):
    kategorie = Kategoria.objects.all()
    context = {'kategorie': kategorie}
    return render(request, 'ogloszenia/index.html', context=context)
```

and on the end in **html** file:

```
{% for kategoria in kategorie %}
{{kategoria.name}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

In this case I have in browser all records belongs to Kategoria class(category and subcategory are together). How to write a def in views to have categories and subcategories seperated for example like in attached picture
[image]

And on the end, how to dislpay how many records are included for example in category : Business - (256) ??

Comment: No one know the solution?

Comment: Think you might find this library useful https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt, this will give you some good functionality to retrieve subcategories from the root category.

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
category=Kategoria.objects.filter(parent=None)
sub_category=Kategoria.objects.exlude(parent=None)
```

Comment: Could you update this answer to explain why this will solve the asker's problem?